# Tensorflow: Compute Hessian matrix (only diagonal part) with respect to a high rank tensor

Tags: tensorflow, mathematical-optimization, derivative, hessian-matrix

I would like to compute the first and the second derivatives(diagonal part of Hessian) of my specified Loss with respect to each feature map of a vgg16 conv4_3 layer's kernel which is a 3x3x512x512 dimensional matrix. I know how to compute derivatives if it is respected to a low-rank one according to [How to compute all second derivatives (only the diagonal of the Hessian matrix) in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200982/how-to-compute-all-second-derivatives-only-the-diagonal-of-the-hessian-matrix)
However, when it turns to higher-rank, I got completed lost.

```
# Inspecting variables under Ipython notebook
In  : Loss 
Out : <tf.Tensor 'local/total_losses:0' shape=() dtype=float32>

In  : conv4_3_kernel.get_shape() 
Out : TensorShape([Dimension(3), Dimension(3), Dimension(512), Dimension(512)])

## Compute derivatives
Grad = tf.compute_gradients(Loss, conv4_3_kernel)
Hessian = tf.compute_gradients(Grad, conv4_3_kernel)

In  : Grad 
Out : [<tf.Tensor 'gradients/vgg/conv4_3/Conv2D_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter:0' shape=(3, 3, 512, 512) dtype=float32>]

In  : Hessian 
Out : [<tf.Tensor 'gradients_2/vgg/conv4_3/Conv2D_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter:0' shape=(3, 3, 512, 512) dtype=float32>]
```

Please help me to check my understandings. So, for `conv4_3_kernel`, each dim stand for [Kx, Ky, in_channels, out_channels], so `Grad` should be partial derivatives of `Loss` with respect to each element(pixel) in the each feature maps. And `Hessian` is the second derivatives.

But, `Hessian` computes all the derivatives, how can I only compute only the diagonal part? should I use `tf.diag_part()`?  Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tf.compute_gradients` computes derivative of a scalar quantity. If the quantity provided isn't scalar, it turns it into scalar by summing up the components which is what's happening in your example

To compute full Hessian you need `n` calls to `tf.gradients`, The example is [here](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/d/msg/discuss/Xb_lwMIsNPc/sLk7aNcZCQAJ). If you want just the diagonal part, then modify arguments to `i`th call to `tf.gradients` to differentiate with respect to `i`th variable, rather than all variables.

Comment: Thank you Yaroslav!

Comment: I used `tf.gradients` to compute derivatives, but it always gives `None` whenever differentiated with respect a specified variable. e.g., `Grad = tf.gradients(Loss, conv4_3_kernel) ` then `Hessian0` = tf.gradients(Grad[...,0], conv4_3_kernel[...,0]) ` gives `None` for all the 512 dims.  Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: From your answer in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200982/how-to-compute-all-second-derivatives-only-the-diagonal-of-the-hessian-matrix), I finally realized my problem was my loss does not depend on `slice` op. So I need to reconstruct my loss with tf.pack-ed variables. Many thanks again!