# Diagonal of the Hessian with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, hessian

I'm doing some machine learning and I have to deal with a custom loss function. The derivatives and the Hessian of the loss function are difficult to derive and so I've resorted to computing them automatically using Tensorflow.

Here is an example.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
], dtype=float)

y_pred = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
], dtype=float)

weights = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=float)

with tf.Session():

    # We first convert the numpy arrays to Tensorflow tensors
    y_true = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_true)
    y_pred = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)
    weights = tf.convert_to_tensor(weights)

    # The following code block is a custom loss 
    ys = tf.reduce_sum(y_true, axis=0)
    y_true = y_true / ys
    ln_p = tf.nn.log_softmax(y_pred)
    wll = tf.reduce_sum(y_true * ln_p, axis=0)
    loss = -tf.tensordot(weights, wll, axes=1)

    grad = tf.gradients(loss, y_pred)[0]

    hess = tf.hessians(loss, y_pred)[0]
    hess = tf.diag_part(hess)

    print(hess.eval())
```

which prints out

```
[[0.24090069 0.12669198 0.12669198 0.12669198 0.12669198]
 [0.12669198 0.24090069 0.12669198 0.12669198 0.12669198]
 [0.12669198 0.12669198 0.12669198 0.24090069 0.12669198]
 [0.12669198 0.12669198 0.24090069 0.12669198 0.12669198]
 [0.04223066 0.04223066 0.04223066 0.04223066 0.08030023]
 [0.04223066 0.04223066 0.04223066 0.04223066 0.08030023]
 [0.04223066 0.04223066 0.04223066 0.04223066 0.08030023]]
```

I'm happy with this because it works, the problem is that it doesn't scale. For my use case I only need the diagonal of the Hessian matrix. I've managed to extract it using `hess = tf.diag_part(hess)` but this will still compute the full Hessian, which is unnecessary. The overhead is so bad that I can't use it for moderate sized datasets (~100k rows).

My question is thus: **is there any better way to extract the diagonal of the Hessian**? I'm well aware of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200982/how-to-compute-all-second-derivatives-only-the-diagonal-of-the-hessian-matrix) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101165/tensorflow-compute-hessian-matrix-only-diagonal-part-with-respect-to-a-high-r) but I don't find the answers good enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow: Compute Hessian matrix (only diagonal part) with respect to a high rank tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101165/tensorflow-compute-hessian-matrix-only-diagonal-part-with-respect-to-a-high-r)

Comment: I'm aware about the link you provided but it's really unclear, plus the Tensorflow API has changed sinced then.

Comment: Posaible duplicate is not inherently bad. Just means that the question is closely tied to another one. So with this we provide a permanent record of the link between both questions.