# How to compute the second derivatives (diagonal of the Hessian) in TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, hessian-matrix

I would like to compute the second derivatives (diagonal hessian) for all the components of all my variables in TensorFlow 2.0. I would like to autograph such a function as well.

I have it working in eager-mode on Google Colab (with a little test as well):

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x  # for colab
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable([[1.], [2.]])
z = tf.Variable([[3., 4.]])

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
    y = (z @ x)**2

  grads = tape2.gradient(y, [x, z])
  # We want references to each component of our Variables in-order
  # This needs to be done in the gradient tape, otherwise, we can't take
  # gradients w.r.t. each component individually
  grads_list = [list(tf.reshape(grad, [-1])) for grad in grads]

second_derivatives_list = []
for grad_list, var in zip(grads_list, [x, z]):
  # Gradient with respect to x returns has the same shape as x
  # So, we get the component that corresponds with the gradient in grads_list
  temp = tf.stack([
    tf.reshape(tape.gradient(g, var), [-1])[i] for i, g in enumerate(grad_list)
  ])
  second_derivatives_list.append(tf.reshape(temp, var.shape))

del tape

assert list(second_derivatives_list[0].numpy().transpose()[0]) == [18., 32.]
assert list(second_derivatives_list[1].numpy()[0]) == [2., 8.]
```

But this implementation is slow and I cannot get it to work with Autograph. Does anyone have a better way to do this? Is there a way to take the gradient of a single component of a tensor without getting a reference to it in the tape? Thanks in advance!

Here are answers for TF 1.x: [How to compute all second derivatives (only the diagonal of the Hessian matrix) in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200982/how-to-compute-all-second-derivatives-only-the-diagonal-of-the-hessian-matrix), [Tensorflow: Compute Hessian matrix (only diagonal part) with respect to a high rank tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40101165/tensorflow-compute-hessian-matrix-only-diagonal-part-with-respect-to-a-high-r).