# Calculate prediction derivation in own loss function

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

in addition to the MSE of y_true and y_predict i would like to use the second derivative of y_true in the cost function, because my model is currently very dynamic. Suppose I have y_predicted (256, 100, 1). The first dimension corresponds to the samples (delta_t between each sample is 0.1s). Now I would like to differentiate via the first dimension, i.e.

```
diff(diff(y_predicted[1, :, 1]))/delta_t**2
```

for each row (0-dim) in y_predictied.

Note, I only want to use y_predicted and delta_t to differentiate

Thank you very much,
Max

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compute all second derivatives (only the diagonal of the Hessian matrix) in Tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200982/how-to-compute-all-second-derivatives-only-the-diagonal-of-the-hessian-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the second order derivative you could use `tf.hessians` as follow:

```
x = tf.Variable([7])
x2 = x * x
d2x2 = tf.hessians(x2, x)
```

Evaluating d2x2 yields:

```
[array([[2]], dtype=int32)]
```

In your case, you could do

```
loss += lam_l1 * tf.hessians(y_pred, xs)
```

where `xs` are the tensors with respect to which you would like to differentiate.

If you wish to use Keras directly, you can chain twice `keras.backend.gradients(loss, variables)`, there is no Keras equivalent of `tf.hessians`.

Comment: @Schaefma3 please, do not use the comments space for posting code (it is literally unreadable!) or for such long clarifications - edit & update your question instead!